# How do I display a stack trace in XSL 2.0 with Saxon?

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am using XSL 2.0 and Saxon 9.5 EE.

I am looking for something like:

```
<xsl:message>Stack trace: <saxon:getCallStack /></xsl:message>
```

I want to use it in a template for debugging purposes, for example in `myFile.xsl`:

```
<xsl:template name="myTemplate">
  <xsl:message>Stack trace: <saxon:displayCallStack /></xsl:message>
  (...)
</xsl:template>
```

When I invoke it in header.xsl:

```
<xsl:call-template name="myTemplate">
```

The header.xsl was included in transform.xsl:

```
<xsl:import href="header.xsl" />
```

I would like to see for example the files with line numbers:

```
Stack trace:
    myFile.xsl:32
    header.xsl:123
    transform.xsl:10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Saxon extension function saxon:print-stack()

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/print-stack

Like all Saxon extension functions, this needs Saxon-PE or higher.